# Prove that $L_{6k} \equiv 2$ (mod $4$)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

Here is my reasoning so far

$L_{6k} =F_{6k-1} + F_{6k+1}$

I have proved that any $F_n$ with n a multiple of 3 is even

i.e. $F_{3n}$ is even and so is $F_{6n}$, it follows that $F_{6k-1}$ and $F_{6k+1}$ are odd and an odd $+$ and odd $=$ an even.

Therefore, $L_{6k} = $ an even number

the following is where I am stuck

I have this conjecture

an even number $\equiv 2$ (mod $4$)

Comment: 4, 8, 12 etc. are all even, yet none is $\equiv2\pmod4$.

Comment: Modulo 4, the Lucas sequence is 2, 1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3,0$\ldots$ isn't it?

Comment: Yes 4,8, 12 etc are all even and none is $\equiv  2$ (mod 4). I can't see the fault on the reasoning I have so far although I know it doesn't work out I like to see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we prove that $F_{6n-3}\equiv2\%4,$ where $\%$ is the modulo operation, by induction. For $n=0$ we have $F_{-3}=2\equiv2\%4.$ Assume that $F_{6n-3}\equiv2\%4,$ then \begin{align}
F_{6n+3}&=F_{6n+2}+F_{6n+1}\\&=2F_{6n+1}+F_{6n}\\&=3F_{6k}+2F_{6n-1}\\&=5F_{6n-1}+3F_{6n-2}\\&=8F_{6n-2}+5F_{6n-3}\\&\equiv5F_{6n-3}\%4\\&\equiv10\%4\\&\equiv2\%4,
\end{align} hence $F_{6n-3}\equiv2\%4$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Now we prove that $L_{6n}\equiv2\%4$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ \begin{align}
L_{6n}&=F_{6n+1}+F_{6n-1}\\&=F_{6n}+2F_{6n-1}\\&=3F_{6n-1}+F_{6n-2}\\&=4F_{6n-2}+3F_{6n-3}\\&\equiv3F_{6n-3}\%4\\&\equiv6\%4\\&\equiv2\%4.
\end{align}

Comment: What property did you use for $8F_{6n-2} + 5F_{6n-3} \equiv 5F_{6n-3}$ (mod $4$) ?

Comment: @winterMute $8F_{6n-2}\equiv0\%4$